# Ansible string variable to Terraform list(string)

Tags: azure, variables, ansible, terraform

I use Ansible and Terraform together for different deployments within MS Azure. Now I want to create a Vnet with Subnets with the module `“azurerm_virtual_network and azurerm_subnet”.` Only I run into the problem that `“Address_space” and “address_prefixes”` are defined in terraform as `“list (string)”` and this is done in Ansible by `“string”`.

My question is how I get this variable from Ansible to Terraform in the correct form without getting the following message:

> “default     = \u001b[4m"{{subnet1_cidr}}"\u001b[0m\n\u001b[0m\nThis
> default value is not compatible with the variable's type constraint:
> list\nof string”

I get the ansible vars `“group_vars”` using an ansible role that copies a file called `“terraform.tfvars.j2”` to `“{{playbook_dir}} / terraform / terraform.tfvars "`. in the `“variables.tf”` the variables are loaded as follow

```
variable "vnet_cidr" {
  type        = list(string)
  default     = "{{ [vnet_cidr] | list | to_json }}"
}

variable "subnet1_cidr" {
  type        = list(string)
  default     = "{{ [subnet1_cidr] | list | to_json }}"
}

variable "subnet2_cidr" {
  type        = list(string)
  default     = "{{ [subnet2_cidr] | list | to_json }}"
}
```

Ansible Group_Vars,

```
VNET_Name: AZ-Venet
GV_Virtual_Network_Cidr: 10.0.0.0/16

SNET1_Name: AZ-FrontEnd
GV_Subnet_Cidr1: 10.0.1.0/24
Survey_SNET2_Name: Az-Backend
GV_Subnet_Cidr2: 10.0.2.0/24
```

Terraform terraform.tfvars.j2 /terraform.tfvars

```
# Networking
vnet_cidr                       = "{{ GV_Virtual_Network_Cidr }}"
subnet1_cidr                    = "{{ GV_Subnet_Cidr1 }}"
subnet2_cidr                    = "{{ GV_Subnet_Cidr2 }}"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you just need to convert string to list with one item, you can use Ansible filters.
Here is an example:

```
{{ [example_variable] | list | to_json }}
```

However in your case there would be a bit different configuration.

In variables.tf file you can try to remove default values, as it seems you do not have variables vnet_cidr, subnet1_cidr and subnet2_cidr in Ansible vars.

variables.tf file will look like this:

```
variable "vnet_cidr" {
  type        = list(string)
  default     = []
}

variable "subnet1_cidr" {
  type        = list(string)
  default     = []
}

variable "subnet2_cidr" {
  type        = list(string)
  default     = []
}
```

Then file terraform.tfvars.j2 /terraform.tfvars will look like this:

```
# Networking
vnet_cidr                       = [ "{{ GV_Virtual_Network_Cidr }}" ]
subnet1_cidr                    = [ "{{ GV_Subnet_Cidr1 }}" ]
subnet2_cidr                    = [ "{{ GV_Subnet_Cidr2 }}" ]
```

Comment: The init stage went fine, but it now went wrong with the apply with the following error message : Invalid value for input variable\n\n  on terraform.tfvars line 22:\n  22: vnet_cidr                       = \"10.0.0.0/16\"\n\nThe given value is not valid for variable \"vnet_cidr\": list of

Comment: May you please give an example of Ansible variable values for vnet_cidr, subnet1_cidr and subnet2_cidr?

Comment: Ansible group_var: 'GV_Virtual_Network_Cidr: 10.0.0.0/16' is vnet_cidr

Comment: Do you have vnet_cidr variable defined in Ansible or you use variable GV_Virtual_Network_Cidr in Ansible?

Comment: GV_Virtual_Network_Cidr is the Ansible variable. Vnet_cidr is the terraform variable

Comment: Just for clarification. 
You are using Ansible variables {{vnet_cidr}}, {{subnet1_cidr}} and {{subnet2_cidr}} in Terraform  variables.tf file. These variables have to be defined in Ansible group_vars or if you use other corresponding variables in Ansible like GV_Virtual_Network_Cidr, your variables.tf should look like
variable "vnet_cidr" {
  type        = list(string)
  default     = "{{ [GV_Virtual_Network_Cidr] | list }}"
}
...

Comment: I also made some changes, try to use following syntax
{{ [example_variable] | list | to_json }}

Comment: Tried but run into the same message as before .. I put the different variable files in my post hopefully that makes it clear

Comment: In variables.tf you are trying to reference variable as default value that does not exist in Ansible.
I updated my answer, may you please check the solution?